# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u266a' in position 16043: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, encoding

so i just started learning web scraping and i ran into this error

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website = 'https://subslikescript.com/series/Game_of_Thrones-944947/season-1/episode-1-Winter_Is_Coming'
response = requests.get(website)
result = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')

box = soup.find('article', class_='main-article')
title = box.find('h1').get_text()
plot = soup.find('p', class_='plot').get_text()
transcript = soup.find('div', class_='full-script').get_text()

with open(title+'.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(plot)
    file.write(transcript)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u266a' in position 16043: character maps to undefined
```

but when adding encoding='utf-8' like this
`with open(title+'.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:`

i dont get any error but the issue is the file isnt being written as a "txt" file and when i open it with notepad, its blank

but, when i remove the title variable and just go with a random name like 'file.txt' as in
`with open('file.txt', 'w' ,encoding='utf-8') as file:`

the code works, i dont get any error and the file is being written as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to make `sanitized_title` vs title.

```
import re
sanitized_title = re.sub(r'[\\/*?:"<>|]', '', title)
with open(sanitized_title + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(plot)
    file.write(transcript)
```